# php base64 iphone picture to webservice

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, base64

i need your help please and i haven't found some answers for my problem.

I want to take a picture (or take it from the gallery) on the iphone/ipad and then encode the picture to a base64 string with php and send the base64 string to a webservice.

If i try it on the pc, everything is alright.
if i want to do this on the ipad, it seems like nothing or a incorrect base64 string is send to the webservice but i have no idea why or so?!

picture.php

```
<form action="picture.php?action=upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="datei" accept="capture=camcorder">
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="up">
</form>
<?
if(isset($_GET['action']))
{

    $tmp_name = $_FILES["datei"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["datei"]["name"];
    $name = substr($name,0,-4);
    $name.="_".time().".jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/".$name);

    $content = file_get_contents ( "upload/".$name );
    $imageBase = base64_encode( $content );

    $success = savePicture($imageBase);
}
```

function savePicture()

```
function savePicture($pic_base64)
{
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
    $pageURL = 'http://....';
    $page = new NTLMSoapClient($pageURL);

    $params = array("pRecordID" => "1",
                  "pFieldID" => 70000,
                  "pUserID" => "153",
                  "pContent" => $pic_base64
                  );

   $result = $page->SetBLOBValue($params);

   if($result->return_value != "ERROR")
   {
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    return false;
   }
}
```

Any Ideas why this didn't work on ipad/iphone?

i hope anybody could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The Problem is that the SOAP Service had a Max-Size for the Files for 1MB!
That was the Problem why i can't upload Base64 Strings who are bigger than 1MB!

Now we increase the Max-Size for Files to 10MB and now it works!

And that was the reason why i cant upload some pictures because some pictures was bigger than 1mb in the base64 string.

Thx for help to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the iPhone/iPad has some problems with `capture=camcorder`.

Please try this:

```
<input type="file" name="datei" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

instead of

```
<input type="file" name="datei" accept="capture=camcorder">
```

For more information check this:

http://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: thx for this, but i not solved the problem :/ 

somtetimes i get a notice after i upload a photo
Notice: Trying to geht proberty of non-object in .... on line 74, and line 74 is if($result->return_value != "ERROR")
So i think i've send incorrect data to the webservice? or the base64 is not correct?

Comment: Does `$pic_base64` look okay inside your `savePicture` function?

Comment: yes it looks okay in the savePicture function!
for example i make a echo in the savePicture and after i called the savePicture, the strings look like the same... but i havent checked any character in the string.

Comment: Ok, what's the value of `$result` after calling `$page->SetBLOBValue($params)`?

Comment: if i get the error on line 74:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www..... on line 74

Result is NULL

Comment: Ok, so you have to read the documentation of `SetBLOBValue` method and check in which cases it returns `NULL`. I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with `NTLMSoapClient` so that I cannot help you.

Comment: i dont know why but i dont get the notice always. sometimes i get it on the pc and on the ipad i get i always?!

on the pc i can upload a few of pictures and after a few pictures i get the notice... on the ipad i get the notice always?